# D365 (On-Prem): Update 'LinkedTo" Entity field with "LinkedFrom" Entity field using QueryExpression

Tags: c#, join, dynamics-crm, updates, query-expressions

The following is my QE to get the result set with columns I need with foreach loop:

```
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Workflow;
using System;
using System.Activities;
using Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Query;

namespace UpdtPrntInvQuants
{
    public class UpdtPrntInvQuants : CodeActivity
    {
        protected override void Execute(CodeActivityContext executionContext)
        {
            ITracingService tracer = executionContext.GetExtension<ITracingService>();
            IWorkflowContext context = executionContext.GetExtension<IWorkflowContext>();
            IOrganizationServiceFactory serviceFactory = executionContext.GetExtension<IOrganizationServiceFactory>();
            IOrganizationService service = serviceFactory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            try
            {
                Entity entity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                //TODO: Do stuff
                Guid shiGuid = entity.Id;

                QueryExpression qe0 = new QueryExpression();
                qe0.EntityName = entity.LogicalName;
                qe0.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet();
                qe0.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("new_shid");
                qe0.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("new_name");
                qe0.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("new_claimed");
                qe0.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("new_ii");
                qe0.ColumnSet.Columns.Add("new_prod");
                qe0.Criteria = new FilterExpression();
                qe0.Criteria.AddCondition("new_shid", ConditionOperator.Equal, shiGuid);

                LinkEntity ii = new LinkEntity("new_sh", "new_ii", "new_prod", "new_prod", JoinOperator.Inner);
                ii.Columns = new ColumnSet("new_qohm", "new_qoht", "new_qohg");
                ii.EntityAlias = "ii";

                qe0.LinkEntities.Add(ii);

                EntityCollection shis = service.RetrieveMultiple(qe0);

                foreach (var shi in shis.Entities)
                {
                    tracer.Trace("SHI: ");
                    tracer.Trace("new_shId: " + shI["new_shid"]);
                    tracer.Trace("new_name: " + shI["new_name"]);
                    tracer.Trace("new_claimed: " + shI["new_claimed"]);
                    tracer.Trace("II: ");
                    tracer.Trace("ii qohm: " + (shI.Attributes["ii.new_qohm"] as AliasedValue).Value);
                    tracer.Trace("ii qoht: " + (shI.Attributes["ii.new_qoht"] as AliasedValue).Value); ;
                    tracer.Trace("ii qohg: " + (shI.Attributes["ii.new_qohg"] as AliasedValue).Value);



                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see I can get the value from the linked entity in the loop above:

```
tracer.Trace("ii qohm: " + (shI.Attributes["ii.new_qohm"] as AliasedValue).Value);
```

Having a hard time setting it to a value from linked entity.

So basically I want to set for example:

`(shI.Attributes["ii.new_qohm"] as AliasedValue).Value) = shI["new_claimed"]` within the loop?

Any suggestions would be fantastic.  I have already tried `setAttributeValue`.

Comment: I don't think you can update link entities. I think you need to have two entities (`shI` and `ii`)

Comment: What do you think updating the values of an `Entity` returned from a `QueryExpression` will do? What is the overall goal here?

Comment: @JamesWood What I want to do is similar to UPDATE FROM JOIN in SQL

Comment: @jasonscript was right, I had to get the GUID from ER and pass into other Entity param

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone said & you realized, `service.RetrieveMultiple` using `QueryExpression` will give you `EntityCollection`, if you want to update back each entity then compose a new Entity object with minimal attributes & update using `service.Update`.